# UITextView removes newline break and <br> tag

Tags: html, ios, swift, uitextview, nsattributedstring

UITextView with attributed html text removes newline break and "br" tags when it has small size.

Here html text for example:

```
let text = """
<h2><font color=\"gray\">Offer</font></h2><br><br><b><font color=\"red\">
            Offer 1:</font></b><br><b>1 kg Sugar Free!</b><br><p>Every purchase above 500 <br>    valid till 23rd April</p>
"""
```

And when line break mode for text view is set to `.byTruncatingTail`, then UITextView removes newline breaks.

Collapsed state (there is not newline break, UITextView removed it)

[image: Collapsed]

Expanded state (there is newlines breaks according to raw HTML)

[image: Expanded]

Expanded and collapsed state controlled by changing Height constraint of UITextView
Here is the project [sample](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1I30UUXE0X-IvkBmsRzQT94toVfizZ17N)
In this project I am waiting that in collapsed state will be 3 lines: link, newline, newline (text should not be visible).